# MySQL c++ connector how to retrieve auto increment keys from insertion query

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using mysql C++ connector. I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table 
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    col1 INT, 
    col2 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

To insert multiple records in a query, I use:

```
INSERT INTO some_table
    (col1, col2)
VALUES
    (0, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (4, 5);
```

My question is: After the insertion, I would like to retrieve all the auto-generated ids. Is it possible that I could use a function in the c++ connector without creating another query?

For example, in the JDBC, the AUTO_INCREMENT column values can be retrieved by using following method.

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO autoIncTutorial (dataField) "
        + "values ('Can I Get the Auto Increment Field?')",
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

//
// Example of using Statement.getGeneratedKeys()
// to retrieve the value of an auto-increment
// value
//

int autoIncKeyFromApi = -1;

rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

if (rs.next()) {
    autoIncKeyFromApi = rs.getInt(1);
} else {

    // throw an exception from here
}
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-last-insert-id.html

Any c++ connector alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: To be honest I've always found the interface of mysqlcpp archaic and clunky. I went back to using the mysql c library directly.

Comment: From the comments in my program:  For auto increment ID fields, the ID field needs to be loaded. The SQL function LAST_STATEMENT_ID() may not return the correct value, especially if the record wasn't updated or the insert didn't result in a new (incremented) record ID. The only safe, reliable method to get the updated ID is to reload the ID field from the table.

Comment: @RichardHodges, is the keys can be retrieved by using c API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last year I faced the same problem. The solution was to use the builtin [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Following I changed the [getting start example 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html) to show how to use it:

```
    //previous variable declarations and initialisation similar to the original example
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
    con->setSchema("test_schema");

    con->setAutoCommit(false);

    stmt = con->createStatement();
    stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl__test1");
    stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_test2");

    const string createTbl1Statement = "CREATE TABLE `tbl__test1` ("
            "`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "`col_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

    const string createTbl2Statement = "CREATE TABLE `tbl_test2` ("
            "`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "`tbl_test1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,"
            "`col_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

    stmt->execute(createTbl1Statement);
    stmt->execute(createTbl2Statement);

    pstmt = con->prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO tbl__test1(col_value) VALUES ('abcde')");
    pstmt->executeUpdate();
    delete pstmt;

    stmt->execute("SET @lastInsertId = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    delete stmt;

    const string insertTbl2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_test2(tbl_test1_id, col_value)" 
            " VALUES (@lastInsertId, '1234')";

    pstmt = con->prepareStatement(insertTbl2);
    pstmt->executeUpdate();
    delete pstmt;

    con->commit();

    delete con;
    //remain code is like the example 2 from mysql site
```

About how safe is call LAST_INSERT_ID(), as stated in the mysql docs:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

EDIT:

As given [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> With no argument, LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a 64-bit value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

Thus, the LAST_INSERT_ID returns the last generated id regardless the table where the new row was insert. If you need to insert several rows just call LAST_INSERT_ID immediately after insert each row such you want to get the key.

In the following code it is inserted 1 row in the table 1, get the generated key (returns '1') than that key is used for insert news 2 rows in the associated table 2. Than again it is inserted 1 new row in the table 1, get generated key again (returns '2') and inserted 2 news rows again in the table 2:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Let's have MySQL count from 10 to 1..." << endl;

    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt1;
        sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt2;

        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        con->setSchema("test_schema");

        con->setAutoCommit(false);

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl__test1");
        stmt->execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_test2");

        const string createTbl1Statement = "CREATE TABLE `tbl__test1` ("
            "`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "`col_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

        const string createTbl2Statement = "CREATE TABLE `tbl_test2` ("
            "`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
            "`tbl_test1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,"
            "`col_value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,"
            "PRIMARY KEY (`id`)"
            ") ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

        stmt->execute(createTbl1Statement);
        stmt->execute(createTbl2Statement);

        pstmt1 = con->prepareStatement(
            "INSERT INTO tbl__test1(col_value) VALUES (?)");

        pstmt1->setString(1, "abcde");
        pstmt1->executeUpdate();

        stmt->execute("SET @lastInsertId = LAST_INSERT_ID()");

        const string insertTbl2 =
            "INSERT INTO tbl_test2(tbl_test1_id, col_value)"
                    " VALUES (@lastInsertId, ?)";
        pstmt2 = con->prepareStatement(insertTbl2);

        pstmt2->setString(1, "child value 1");
        pstmt2->executeUpdate();

        pstmt2->setString(1, "child value 2");
        pstmt2->executeUpdate();

        pstmt1->setString(1, "xpto");
        pstmt1->executeUpdate();

        stmt->execute("SET @lastInsertId = LAST_INSERT_ID()");

        pstmt2->setString(1, "child value 3");
        pstmt2->executeUpdate();

        pstmt2->setString(1, "child value 4");
        pstmt2->executeUpdate();

        con->commit();

        delete stmt;
        delete pstmt1;
        delete pstmt2;

        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result is the 2 rows in table 1:

[image: 2 rows inserted in table 1]

And 4 rows in the table 2 each one properly associated with the key in table 1:

[image: 4 rows inserted in table 2]

So, the key point is to call LAST_INSERT_ID() after insert the new row with the generated key you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in your answer, one record is inserted. I am trying to insert multiple records. Based on my understanding, the query LAST_INSERT_ID() only returns 1 id, is that right?

Comment: In the first example It is inserted 1 row in the table 1 and 1 row in the table 2. Please refer to my edit where I had provide a full example where several rows are inserted in both tables.